# Como fazer uma função retornar resultado apenas após click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando se utiliza a função `confirm()` em JavaScript, geralmente é assim:

```
var resultado = confirm("Deseja realmente confirmar?");
if(resultado){
    //confirmou...
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer a mesma coisa com uma função própria, exemplo:

```
var resultado = minhaCofirmacao("Deseja realmente confirmar?");
if(resultado){
    //...
}
```

Aqui vai um exemplo da função (só com as partes práticas da pergunta): [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/LguHE/1/)

Eu tentei fazer isso criando um listener para quando o usuário clicasse no botão de confirmação da minha função, mas ela retorna antes de o usuário disparar o evento por si só.

Existe alguma forma de se criar este tipo de `return` dependente de uma ação do usuário **sem ser com callback**?

Comment: O problema é que o `confirm` é sincrono e o JS pára e fica à espera da resposta. Acho que isso vai impedir/limitar o que você quer. Quando queria disparar essa pergunta/pedido de confirmação?

Comment: "sem ser com callback?" -- sim, e não. Pode fazer de outras formas, como com Promises, mas mesmo assim não vai ser código síncrono como eu acho que você espera.

Comment: Cenário: eu mando deletar um item de uma lista, ele me manda essa confirmação e, de acordo com a minha resposta, toma uma ação. (ela possui algumas outras opções que o `confirm()` tradicional não possui, por isso ele não é utilizado).

Comment: @Kazzkiq, sem usar `callback`, acredito que seja difícil (ou pouco pratico), pois o JS é assíncrono por natureza(o que eu acho otimo), e vai mostrar o "minhaConfirmacao" e continuar seu curso. De qualquer forma, não entendo o problema em mover o curso da aplicação para um `callback`? Se puder especificar o motivo pelo qual não gostaria de usar `callback` para podermos entender melhor sua necessidade, assim talvez possamos lhe ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer tudo através do JQuery assim:

```
var div = $("<div />").addClass("popup").appendTo($("body"));

$("<button />").append("Confirmar?").appendTo(div).click(function() {
    var confirmou = confirm("Deseja realmente confirmar?");
    if (confirmou) {
        alert("Confirmou! =)");
    } else {
        alert("Não confirmou... =(");
    }
});
```

Note que criei uma div com a classe popup que você criou e depois só adicionei o botão a essa div. Espero que resolva seu problema.